# Algorithms for finding clique in bounded-degree graph

Tags: graph-algorithms

Consider a graph with $n$ vertices and maximum degree $\Delta$. I would like to find if the graph has any $s$ cliques, where $s \leq \Delta$ and both of them are small compared to $n$. I only need to find a single such clique (or certify that none exist)

There is a straightforward way to do this: for each vertex $v$, test all $s$-subsets of the neighbors of $v$. The work is thus $\approx n \binom{\Delta}{s-1}$.

Are there any more efficient algorithms than this? Even achieving an exponential speed-up would be good?

Comment: Don't you have $s\leq\Delta$?

Comment: A positive answer to this question will imply clique can be solved in $n^{o(s)}$ time.  Note that $\Delta<n$.  Or equivalently, consider solve the clique problem in $N[v]$ for each vertex $v$.

Comment: @Yixin, I would be interested even in solutions that take time say $n \Delta^{c(s-1)}/(s-1)!$, where $c < 1$ is a constant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Eppstein, Löffler, and Strash modified the Bron-Kerbosch algorithm, obtaining an algorithm that lists [all maximal cliques in $O(dn 3^{d/3})$ time](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-17517-6_36#page-1), where $d$ is the degeneracy of the graph (note $d \le \Delta$).

The same idea [can be extended for the maximum clique problem in $d$-degenerate graphs](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11590-013-0698-2), and the runtime can be improved to $O^*(2^{d/4})$.